# Setting repository size limit on a remote bare repo

Tags: git

Is it possible to set a repository size limit for the git-receive-pack command? Or do I have to do the size check myself?

Github has this function: https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/, but I have no idea how they've implemented it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution, but not complete, is to set `receive.maxInputSize` for your `git config`.
Remember that you'll need a relatively new version of git, i.e. version 2.11 or later I think.